# Excel Formula - Making the concatenate cells showing a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to show my Concatenate(SumIf formula resulting into a text cell that shows the formula of two cells.
So for example, I have:

Row 1: List of Dates.

Column A: I have the dates of clients months.

Column B: I have names

Column C: I have the totals

What I'm trying to do is showing what adding what, so in April it shows Willy twice, and so I want it to show: =C3(5751)+C9(8852)

What I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMTAR.png

Comment: do you mean `=C3(5751)+C6(515485)+C9(8852)+C22(436)`? (because April is actually showing Willy 4 times)

Answer (score 0):

You may try below formula.

```
="="&TEXTJOIN("+",TRUE,FILTER(ADDRESS(ROW(C3:C10),3,4)&"("&C3:C10&")",(A3:A10=D1)*(B3:B10=D2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This one should work if I understood your question correctly:

```
="="&TEXTJOIN("+",TRUE,IF(A3&B3=A3:A25&B3:B25,"C"&ROW(C3:C25)&"("&C3:C25&")",""))
```

There's no reason to use sumif; as the result you want doesn't have the actual sum there.

[image: note that my system uses ; instead of , for separating arguments]